# assign jchararray to const unsigned char

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I pass a char [] from java to jni :

```
function(char [] aChar);
```

then I read the char [] at jni :

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
packagename_function(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jcharArray aChar) {

  const unsigned char *theValue;
}
```

Now I want to assign aChar as a value for theValue.

What is the correct way to assign it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mko for giving me the idea.  My final code is :

```
/* get size of the array */
jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, aChar);

/* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
jchar *body = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, aChar, 0);

jstring mystr =  (*env)->NewString(env, body, len);

/* release body when you decide it is no longer needed */
(*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, aChar, body, 0);

const unsigned char *theValue = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,mystr, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. You can pass array (as you do) and then, you need to retrieve it's elements:

   http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-012/

   ```
   /* get size of the array */
   jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);

   /* get the body of array; it will be referecende by C pointer */
   jchar *body = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, array, 0);

   /* do some stuff */
   for(int i=0; i < len; i++) {
     printf("Char value: %c\n", body[i]);
   }

   /* release body when you decide it is no longer needed */
   (*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, array, body, 0);
   ```
2. You can pass characters as a String object

   http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/

   ```
   // we have to get string bytes into C string
   const char *c_str;
   c_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, str, NULL);
   if(c_str == NULL) {
     return;
   }

   printf("Passed string: %s\n", c_str);

   // after using it, remember to release the memory
   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, str, c_str);
   ```

   In case of passing String from Java to C you have to change two things:

   - You need to change your method signature to

     ```
     packagename_function(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring aChar)
     ```
   - In your Java code, you have to create String from characters

     ```
     char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
     String str = new String(data);
     ```

   and then, pass it to native code.

   Note! Be careful with types lengths! You can always check here:

   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html

Comment: how to put all body element as suggested in 1. as jstring?

Answer (score 0):

In java side, the char is encoding with UTF16, is counter part jni side is unsigned short not unsigned char, so i think if you want to set the java side char array to jni side, you have two options:
1. In java, convert the char array to byte array with UTF8 encoding.
2. Or in jni side, convert the UTF16 encoding string to UTF8 string.
I think the previous option is more convenient.